# Large deviations for maximizer of random walk with drift

Tags: pr.probability, random-walks

Is it easy to write down the large deviations rate for the maximizer of a random walk with negative drift?

Let $X_i$ be the (iid, mean $-\mu$, variance $\sigma$, arbitrarily nice tails) jumps of a random walk $S_i$. I am interested in the location of the maximum of $S_i$, i.e. in $\arg\max_k S_k$. (If $X_i$ are continuous, the maximizer is almost surely unique.)

There's a trivial exponential upper bound
$$
\mathbb{P}(\arg\max_k(S_k) > n) \leq \mathbb{P}(S_{n+1} > 0) = \mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i > 0)
$$
and the trivial exponential lower bound
$$
\mathbb{P}(\arg\max_k(S_k) > n) \geq \mathbb{P}(X_i > 0\ \forall i \leq n)
$$
and they (of course) don't match. Is there a limit
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}n^{-1}\log\mathbb{P}(\arg\max_k(S_k) > n),
$$
and is it possible to write it down in terms of the distribution of the jumps $X_i$?

Comment: The answer of course depends on the tail assumptions for the $X_i$s. Do they have exponential tails? In that case, you have a $\log$ missing in your question, and  the answer can be read off large deviations for the maximum (which are  covered by e.g. Iglehart's 1972 paper).

Comment: Thank you, Ofer! Yes, of course, it should be $\log\mathbb{P}(...)$.

Comment: The system won't let me write a comment cause I'm a new user, so I'll write an answer instead. I have a question in the OP, in the upper bound part, why is it that $$\mathbb{P}(\arg \max_k (S_k)>n)\leq\mathbb{P}(S_{n+1}>0)$$ I don't quite get that part... Any help would be appreciated :-)

Comment: I don't remember if I had a better reason three years ago, but it would definitely true as $\mathbb{P}(\text{arg max}_k(S_k) = n) \leq \mathbb{P}(S_{n+1} > 0)$, which should be close enough from a large deviations standpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The upper bound gives the correct large deviations; that is, the answer is
$$n^{-1}\log P(\mbox{ arg max}_k S_k>n)\to -I(0)\,,$$
where $I(0)=-\inf_\lambda  \log E(e^{\lambda X_1})$.

The upper bound appears in the OP. For the lower bound, just consider the event 
$$ {\cal A}_n:=\{S_n\geq \epsilon n \}$$
and note that 
$P(\mbox{ argmax}_k S_k <n(1-\delta)|{\cal A}_n)$ goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$ if $\delta>>\epsilon$
(but both small). But $n^{-1}\log P({\cal A}_n)\to-I(\epsilon)$. Now use the continuity of $I$ in $\epsilon$ (here you need to assume something on the tails; finite logarithmic mgf is enough).